# lightbox jquery show text

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm using the [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/),  is there a way to show an textfield istead of images or both ?

or maybe another way to show a text in lightbox popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best example video of lightbox
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKflZrGXokY

try [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 1):

Go with this bro... it ll give u the exact what u want
http://www.swsemarketing.com/blog/42/How_To_Create_A_Lightbox_To_Display_Text_Or_Images/

Answer (score 0):

Anything with better animation? ThickBox is dummy in comparison with [Lightbox 2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Answer (score 0):

[FancyBox2](http://fancybox.net/)
is quite good, it has a mac-style design and effects.