# lightbox no image just text?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am currently using light box provided by ... http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

How do I have it so that if I click on a work it brings up the light box and shows text instead of an image?
what I want is the terms and conditions shown up in a lightbox.

**HTML**

```
<span id="terms"> <a href="">Terms & Conditions</a></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
   $('#terms a').lightBox();
});
```

Comment: From reading the docs on the website it seems like it's supposed to work only on images. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496951/lightbox-jquery-show-text

Comment: I was curious to see what hacks people would come up with after reading the question. These aren't really answers to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this lightbox plugin only works with images.
You should choose another plugin like colorbox: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
It's simple to use and supports iframes and also div elements inside the lightbox.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can use the plugin as you desire,because that plugin works with images, in any case specify the text you want to appear in the title of the `<a>`

```
 <a title="this plugin takes text from here" href="">Terms & Conditions</a>
```

But i think you will have to find another plugin

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Fancybox to show content in a lightbox. Create a simple HTML page for your terms and conditions then the page will load within the lightbox.  If Javascript is disabled they will be taken to the page via the link

http://fancybox.net/