# Is there any way to open all types of files (.txt, .doc, .html, .ppt, .jpeg, .png etc) in light box?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is there any way to open all types of files (.txt, .doc, .html, .ppt, .jpeg, .png, also video files.) using asp.net C#?

I have tried color box but I am able to load .html pages only in color box. If i want to open a Word file then I have to convert it to html first. So is there any way to open all files in light box?

Please help.

**EDIT**

I have tries the code from below link
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

What I have done so far is...**My code is as below**

**Default.aspx**

```
 <style type="text/css">
            body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
            a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
            h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example1/colorbox.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
                $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
                $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
                $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
                $(".ajax").colorbox();
                $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
                $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"60%", height:"80%"});
                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
                $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                });

                $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
                $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});
                
                //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                $("#click").click(function(){ 
                    $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ColorBox Demonstration</h1>
        <%--<h2>Elastic Transition</h2>
        <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
        <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
        <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
        
        <h2>Fade Transition</h2>
        <p><a class="group2" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
        <p><a class="group2" href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
        <p><a class="group2" href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
        --%>
        <h2>No Transition + fixed width and height (75% of screen size)</h2>
        <p><a class="group3" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
        <p><a class="group3" href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
        <p><a class="group3" href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
        
    <%--    <h2>Slideshow</h2>
        <p><a class="group4"  href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
        <p><a class="group4"  href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
        <p><a class="group4"  href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
        
        <h2>Other Content Types</h2>
        <p><a class='ajax' href="WordToHtml/Notes.htm" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
        <p><a class='youtube' href="Uploadedfiles/Wildlife.wmv" title="The Knife: We Share Our Mother's Health">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a></p>
        <p><a class='vimeo' href="Uploadedfiles/Wildlife.wmv" title="R&ouml;yksopp: Remind Me">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To Vimeo)</a></p>--%>

        <p><a runat="server" id="a"  class='iframe'>Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
        <%--<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>--%>
        
        <h2>Demonstration of using callbacks</h2>
        <p><a class='callbacks' href="../content/marylou.jpg" title="Marylou on Cumberland Island">Example with alerts</a>. Callbacks and event-hooks allow users to extend functionality without having to rewrite parts of the plugin.</p>
        

    <%--    <h2>Retina Images</h2>
        <p><a class="retina" href="../content/daisy.jpg" title="Retina">Retina</a></p>
        <p><a class="non-retina" href="../content/daisy.jpg" title="Non-Retina">Non-Retina</a></p>

        <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
            <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
            <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p>
            
            <p><strong>If you try to open a new ColorBox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
            <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
            <a class="ajax" href="../content/ajax.html">Click here to load new content</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>--%>
    </body>
</html>
```

**.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.HRef = "~/Uploadedfiles/notes.html";
    }
```

Here i have converted notes.doc file to notes.html.
Here i an able to open .html file. So i want to know is there any way to open word doc. directly in iframe

Comment: Please any one have any idea

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you have done so far. Provide us some code links etc.

Comment: Side note: for your future questions please try to provide links/explanation what "color box", "light box" mean. Also  Shekhar seem to know what you are talking about, you will get much better chance tfor response if you question does not contain unclear terms (i.e. you probbly mean "lightbox plugin" in place of "light box", but maybe not...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this `lightbox plugin` only works with images.
You should choose another plugin like colorbox:
 http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
It's simple to use and supports iframes and also div elements inside the lightbox.

### Edit 1

There are few links which may help you
[lightbox no image just text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618686/lightbox-no-image-just-text)

Comment: my actual scenerio is I have a grid with list of filesname... Now I want that when i click on Filename(LinkButton) the popup should open with file content.... Same as in link http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ , When i click on Outside Webpage (Iframe)

Comment: But here i can only open .html files

Comment: have you gone through this link of the same http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: ya i have gone throught this before i have posted this question in this forum

Comment: But no examples is there which gives an idea to open doc file